# getting fasta sequences(proteome) from a file referencing another fasta file (tf)of the same organism

Tags: fasta

basically I have 2 large fasta sequences file, the first one is the proteome fasta sequences ( all the protein sequences), the second one is the transcription factor sequences fasta file of the same organism, i am just wondering if there is any way that I can extract the non transcriptional sequences as a fasta file using these two files?? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you can, essentially the algorithm is as follows.

1. Read in the transcriptional factor sequences and store as a hash or
   dict.
2. Scan the proteome fasta sequences and if the sequence/position is
   not in the hash/dict then append to array/list.
3. After scanning take the array/list and output in desired format.

The reason why I say hash/dict is depending on if you doing this in python or some other lang.